# Is display:none hidden data embedded in a PDF when printed

Tags: css, pdf

I’m looking to hide sensitive information from a webpage when printing to PDF.

I use a media="print" stylesheet with quite a lot of display:none to do so because I can’t edit the webpage directly.

When using a PDF printer such as "Microsoft Print to PDF", is any of the data hidden by the stylesheet embedded somewhere inside the resulting PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Elements that are set to `display: none` are neither visible or in any form inside a the resulting PDF.

**Longer answer:**
Usually I would say it is hidden completely - like form elements that are set to `display: none` are completely ignored. But since I wasn't sure I did the following to test it:

1. I created a testpage with the only HTML `<div>Hello <span style="display: none">world</span></div>` inside and printed it to PDF.
2. I opened the resulting PDF in Illustrator and inspected the layers. No such sign of the word `world`.

I tested this on a Mac (Chrome) and on Windows (Edge and IE11)